# how can I find each link as a string from html page with Beautiful Soup ? ( findAll function is not finding well for this website)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to add all Dota2 hero names; they are appeared as links, from https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon/Counters into a list.

here is my test code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

my_url = 'https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon/Counters'
print(Child_url+hero_link_list[0])
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "mw-parser-output"})

print(containers)
```

But, after printing the containers variable, almost all information under this div tag is missing, and just some comments are added only.
I don't have any idea why this is happening. after this step, I have an idea to **scrape** the links but first I need to add hole information to containers.

Comment: What exactly your trying to extract & inlude the expected output in your post.

Answer (score 1):

This script will print all here names:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon/Counters'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_heros = [a.text for a in soup.select('b > a')]

#print them:
print(*all_heros, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
Ancient Apparition
Axe
Brewmaster
Doom
Lina
Lion
Mars
Outworld Devourer
Silencer
Shadow Demon
Death Prophet
Mirana
Bane
Batrider
Beastmaster
Chen
Techies
Bloodseeker
Necrophos
Nyx Assassin
Storm Spirit
Phantom Assassin
Io
Axe
Legion Commander
Centaur Warrunner
Oracle
```

---

EDIT (To scrape the categories, you can use `.find_previous()` function):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon/Counters'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = {}
for hero in soup.select('b > a'):
    data.setdefault(hero.find_previous(class_='mw-headline').text, []).append(hero.text)

#print them:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'Bad against...': ['Ancient Apparition',
                    'Axe',
                    'Brewmaster',
                    'Doom',
                    'Lina',
                    'Lion',
                    'Mars',
                    'Outworld Devourer',
                    'Silencer',
                    'Shadow Demon'],
 'Good against...': ['Death Prophet',
                     'Mirana',
                     'Bane',
                     'Batrider',
                     'Beastmaster',
                     'Chen',
                     'Techies',
                     'Bloodseeker',
                     'Necrophos',
                     'Nyx Assassin'],
 'Works well with...': ['Storm Spirit',
                        'Phantom Assassin',
                        'Io',
                        'Axe',
                        'Legion Commander',
                        'Centaur Warrunner',
                        'Oracle']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you describe your code a little bit? And can It be written with findALL? And Also these names are in 3 different categories, how can I scrap those too?

Comment: @babakabdzadeh I updated my answer. It can be done with `.find_all()`, but with a lambda function or more lines of code. CSS selector `b > a` means find all `<a>` tags directly under `<b>` tag.